# Batch: Execute command with quotes in for loop with piping to find

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Could you please advise how to fix command below, which removes unversioned items from svn

```
rem @echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('"c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" status --no-ignore ^| find "?"') do echo %%i
```

variant below without path works:

```
rem @echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn.exe status --no-ignore ^| find "?"') do echo %%i
```

but i need to pass entire path  with svn.exe. In this case it outputs C:\Program is not a valid program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*try with this:*

```
   for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (`"c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" status --no-ignore ^| find "?"`) do echo %%i
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still outputs C:\Program is not a valid program

Comment: sorry it outputs: Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"

Comment: and what about : for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (`'"c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"' status --no-ignore ^| find "?"`) do echo %%i  (use ' toghether with "). YOu can also save the path to the executable to a variable and substitute it in the for loop

Comment: it doesn't actually executes "c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" status --no-ignore, it just outputs the part after space...

Comment: short paths are option too.try to replase "program files" with PROGRA~1

Comment: thanks for variable, but things doesn't change for some reason. there're soooooo black magic.

Comment: Thanks. Your nindzutsu helped. for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('c:\Progra~1\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe status --no-ignore ^| find "?"') do echo %%i

Comment: One more hint: Are you sure you used a back quotes with usebackq parameter.Symbols are different ` (under the escape) and ' .usebackq is created especially for double quotes inside the for loop text.For more info check this: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem, I tried using "usebackq" as suggested in the Windows command reference[1]:

> Specifies to execute a back-quoted string as a command, and a single-quoted string as a literal string command. Also, allows file names in Set to be enclosed in quotation marks.

I found that this still gave an error about C:\Program not being executable.

Then I remembered, that Windows cmd.exe has really weird quoting rules, where if the first and last character in an executed string are quotes, they will be stripped[2].

So I tried this, and it worked for me:

```
for /F usebackq %%d in (`""path to command" arg arg "quoted arg""`) do @echo %%d
```

---

[1] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx

[2] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320.aspx

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you include a real-life example, so that we can check?

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to escape the outer quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924856/2630028

Answer (score 1):

Going off of Ben's answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084830/2630028), the below example worked for me:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%j in (`^""C:\Perl64\bin\perl" -e "print(qq(foo))"^"`) do (
    echo LINE: %%j 
)
```

It seems like I have to escape the outer quotes with `^` (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).