# Windows Batch: Executing command with FOR /F -- "command not found"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-execution

I have a problem with executing an other command within a FOR-command on Windows 7 Ultimate.
The for-command is part of a batch-file and should parse the outputs of another command.

Usually this:

```
for /f %%a IN ('tasklist') DO echo %%a
```

should execute the command "Tasklist" and output its results via echo.
But I always get "command not found".

I tried to execute the command outside of the forloop and it works.
I also tried do execute lots of outer commands within the for, but every command said "command not found".

I also tried the examples of this post:

[Batch: Execute command with quotes in for loop with piping to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755069/batch-execute-command-with-quotes-in-for-loop-with-piping-to-find)

I`m sure

- that the commands exists
- that I have read and execute rights to it
- that my User is in Administrator Group
- that I run the commands with "Run as Administrator"

But nothing is working in this pc.
The same commands work on another PC wich is also running a windows 7 ultimate.

So has anybody an idea would could be wrong on the pc where all commands are not found ?

Here is an example of my console outputs when I try it with the command "ls".
ls.exe is a executable file from the gun4win project, and its located in the same folder where my batch-file is running.
The windows is in german, so the error output is also in german.

C:\test>test_for.bat

```
C:\test>rem --- test a command stand-alone ---   

C:\test>ls 
ls.exe        test_for.bat     

C:\test>rem --- test same command in a FOR-Loop ---   

C:\test>for /F "delims=" %a in ('ls') do echo FOR-OUTPUT: %a 
Der Befehl "ls" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden
werden.
```

**FINAL EDIT:**
The problem was as wrong value for the system envoirement variable `ComSpec`.

I changed ComSpec in `Erweiterte Systemeigenschaften->Erweitert->Umgebungsvariaben->Systemvariablen" to "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` and the problem was solved.

Thanks to @foxidrive and @jeb

Comment: Does your script use a variable with the name `path` ?

Comment: ...or `pathext`? you could try to execute the script in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32\`, where the `tasklist` command is located...

Comment: That doesn`t mater where the command is located. I even tried a command wich is laying in the same folder like my batchfile. Its says "comand not found" for everything. But I can execute all commands outsite of the for. Only within the for no comand is found

Comment: Unlike `'something' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, "command not found" does not seem to be any standard Windows `cmd` error message. Please [edit] your question and add any _real_ particular sample satisfying [mcve]. Copy & paste from `cmd`  window  having `echo ON` active in your batch script.

Comment: @JosefZ `"command not found" does not seem to be any standard Windows cmd error message.` <--- Good point Josef.   It's not a cmd error message.

Comment: If the error message was misquoted, the `comspec` variable might be fubar also, if commands run inside the script but only fail within a for command - as comspec is used to call cmd.exe for each of those commands inside the for.

Comment: command not found was yust a simple translation of the german error message, but now a added example output of my testscript to the question.

Full translated errormessage would be:

`Command "tasklist" is written wrong or cannot be found`

And ComSpec=C:\Temp

Comment: @Radon8472 `comspec` should be `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, as this is the program that will be started in the for loop. If it's really `C:\temp` on your system then FOR /F can't work

Comment: More at [DosTips: ComSpec strange behaviour](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7006)

Comment: Setting ComSpec to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" does not change anything :(

Comment: @Radon8472  If you open a `new` cmd window and type `set comspec` what appears on your console?

Comment: As said, changing ComSpec will be cached. Check/modify your ComSpec setting under `Erweiterte Systemeigenschaften->Erweitert->Umgebungsvariaben->Systemvariablen`

Comment: Changing the System ENV "ComSpec" to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" works now  :)

If you enter this hint as a Answer, you get the Accepted Answer Flag.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `FOR /F` and get the error `'something' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` for every program, even internal commands, the most common cause is a wrong ComSpec variable.

You can check the variable with `set ComSpec`, it should be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

It will not help to change the variable on the command line, the cause is described at [DosTips: ComSpec strange behaviour](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7006)

If the variable contains a different value, you should correct this under

For a German system:
`Erweiterte Systemeigenschaften->Erweitert->Umgebungsvariaben->Systemvariablen`

For an English system:
`Win Key+Pause Key->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->System Variables`

**There exists a second possible cause for strange `FOR /F` behaviour**
If the AutoRun feature can be enabled in the registry `...\Command Processor\AutoRun`, for more details see `cmd /?`.
The AutoRun feature can start a batch file each time a new cmd.exe instance is started.
This can be useful for ex. showing some data on opening a new cmd window or always change to a choosen directory.
But this batch will be also executed inside the `FOR /F` and normally causes unexpected results.
Pipes also start new cmd instances, but suppress the AutoRun script